# Problem with configuration of LiveQuery in Parseplatform

Tags: php, parse-platform, livequery, parse-live-query

Hello i have installed Parse server and parse sdk for php on my Linux Centos Server.
Parse Dashboard: 1.3.3,
Server version: 4.3.0
I'm managing those db's using php code. This parser was installed by someone else. The thing is I'm not sure how to install LiveQuery for my server. I don't know if my version of server is good for this kind of operations. I found some solutions how to enable this feature, but there was something like "index.js" - in my file system it's app.js. [Screen of file system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvtAJ.png)
In app.js i added lines:

```
liveQuery: {
        classNames: ["Test"] //List of classes to support for query subscritions
    }
```

I've created class in my db named "Test", then i found solution i need to add
this line

```
liveQueryUrl: keyLiveQueryUrl, // Required if using LiveQuery
```

I don't really know how to get this key.

How can i check if LiveQuery works? It will be used by flutter code, but i'd like to check it first in PHP.

Comment: I believe PHP implementation does not have live query support. It might be easier you test it out directly on Flutter or using JS SDK.

Comment: Yea but i don't know where i can find liveQueryUrl: keyLiveQueryUrl this.

Comment: By the default it should be something like `wss://yourserveraddress/parse`. Basically same address of your rest api (unless you have setup a different thing on parse server options), but with ws (if you are using http for rest) or wss (if you are using https for rest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem has been solved in my other extended topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68920152/problem-with-setup-livequery-to-work-with-flutter).